# jQuery function asynchronous or not?

Tags: jquery, function, asynchronous

I'm using the following guidelines:

```
(function( $ ){

var methods = {
  init : function( options ) { 
  // THIS 
},
show : function( ) {
  // IS
},
hide : function( ) { 
  // GOOD
},
update : function( content ) { 
  // !!! 
}
};
etc.
```

My question is: if I call one of the functions listed above from one of the other functions listed above, is that an asynchronous call? It sort of looks like it: I'm trying to attach all event handlers in one function, and I call that function after another one, but the event handling is attached somewhere during the previous function execution. Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Calling one method from another does not make it asynchronous.  You would need a truly asynchronous operation like an ajax call, timer, etc... to make something asynchronous.

Calling one handler from within another will just execute the two in order synchronously one immediately after the other.

Comment: that's what I thought, before I noticed my event handlers being attached before the whole array was passed.